# bash - how to iterate a list/array through a parameterized bash script

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I have a bash script where I pass the following arguments (its using getopts) like so:

```
./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tblA -n c13 -r us-east-1
```

The execution works however, I need to alter this where `-t` (for table) needs to be a list of tables `(tblA, tblB, tblC)`.

So, in a single run, I'm trying to generate the following:

```
./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tblA -n c13 -r us-east-1
./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tblB -n c13 -r us-east-1
./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tblC -n c13 -r us-east-1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: for i in A B C; do ./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tbl$i c13 -r us-east-1; done

Comment: Treat the argument to `-t` as a space separated list:  `./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t "tblA tblB tblC" -n c13 -r us-east-1`.  you can then run that argument through another for loop or whatever you need to do inside the script (since you didn't provide any relevant code)

Comment: @xxfelixxx - that works for me. put in as an answer and i will accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `for` loop:

```
for i in A B C; do
    ./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tbl"$i" c13 -r us-east-1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

How about leveraging bash and use variable range? This would make a difference if you have to deal with large range.

```
for i in {A..C}
do
   ./test.sh -o c03 -d mydb -t tbl"$i" c13 -r us-east-1
done
```